# Terraform error - Error: Argument or block definition required

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

My terraform code is as below:

```
terraform {
  backend "remote" {
    hostname     = "hostname.com"
    organization = "companyname"
    workspaces {
      name = "GIT-TIO-DEV"
    }
  }
} 


provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  version = "~> 2.22"
}

locals {
  aws_region                      = "us-east-1"
  ami_id                          = "ami-000db10762d0c4c05"
  appid_tag                       = "S00012"
  env_tag                         = "dev"
  name_tag                        = "TESTINSTANCE"
  awsaccount_tag                  = "myaccount"
  createdby_tag                   = "testuser"
  keyName                         = "tst-cloudservices-portal-dev"
  securityGroup                   = "sg-wwwwwwwww"
  vpc_id                          = "vpc-aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
  patchgroup_tag                  = "GroupA"
  iam_role                        = "tst-SR-ServiceRole"
  division_tag                    = "TIO"
  application_segment_tag         = "DEV"
  notes_tag                       = "link to notes 2"
  function_tag                    = "portal server"
  os_tag                          = "RHEL76"
  platform_tag                    = "Linux"
  instance_type                   = "t2.micro"
  automation_server_count         = 2
}

variable "health_check" {
  description = "A health check block"
  type        = map(string)
  default = {
  "enabled" = "true",
  "port" = "443", 
  "protocol" = "https"
  }

 }

variable listener {
[
    {
        instance_port = "80"
        instance_protocol = "tcp"
    },
    {
        instance_port = "443"
        instance_protocol = "tcp"
    }
]



}
# Adding EC2 afer Security Group

module "tst-security-group-ec2" {
  source                          = "hostname.com/companyname/tst-security-group/aws"
  version                         = "1.0.2"
  group_name                      = "tst-myaccount-portal-dev"
  group_description               = "security group for portal dev"
  vpc_id                          = local.vpc_id
  appid_tag                       = local.appid_tag
  env_tag                         = local.env_tag
  awsaccount_tag                  = local.awsaccount_tag
  createdby_tag                   = local.createdby_tag
  function_tag                    = "Security group for portal dev"
  ingress = [{
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "TCP"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  },{
    from_port   = 3389
    to_port     = 3389
    protocol    = "TCP"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
    },{
    from_port   = -1
    to_port     = -1
    protocol    = "icmp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  }]
  egress =[ {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }]
}
module "ec2-rhel-automation-server" {
  source                          = "hostname.com/companyname/tst-ec2-instance-rhel/aws"
  version                         = "1.2.6"
  aws_region                      = local.aws_region
  vpc_id                          = local.vpc_id
  ami_id                          = local.ami_id
  appid_tag                       = local.appid_tag
  application_segment_tag         = local.application_segment_tag
  awsaccount_tag                  = local.awsaccount_tag
  createdby_tag                   = local.createdby_tag
  default_security_group_id       = module.tst-security-group-ec2.id
  division_tag                    = local.division_tag
  env_tag                         = local.env_tag
  function_tag                    = local.function_tag
  keyName                         = local.keyName
  name_tag                        = "RHEL-AS${local.env_tag}"
  notes_tag                       = local.notes_tag
  os_tag                          = local.os_tag
  platform_tag                    = local.platform_tag
  ec2_server_count                = local.automation_server_count
  instance_type                   = local.instance_type
  hostname_tag                    = "ERNST${local.env_tag}WEB"
  iam_role                        = "tst-SR-ServiceRole"
  bootstrap_instance              = "false"
    }

// Adding ALB Security Group
module "tst-security-group-alb" {
  source                          = "hostname.com/companyname/tst-security-group/aws"
  version                         = "1.0.2"
  group_name                      = "tst-myaccount-portal-dev"
  group_description               = "security group for ALB"
  vpc_id                          = local.vpc_id
  appid_tag                       = local.appid_tag
  env_tag                         = local.env_tag
  awsaccount_tag                  = local.awsaccount_tag
  createdby_tag                   = local.createdby_tag
  function_tag                    = "Security group for ALB"
  ingress = [{
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "TCP"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/8"]

   }]
  egress =[ {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }]
}
// Creating a ALB
module "tst-alb" {
  source                          = "hostname.com/companyname/tst-alb/aws"
  version                         = "1.0.5"
  subnets                         = ["subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxx","subnet-yyyyyyyyyyy","subnet-zzzzzzzzzzzzz"]
  listener                        = var.listener
  createdby_tag                   = local.createdby_tag
  function_tag                    = "Terraform created ALB"
  vpc_id                          = local.vpc_id
  awsaccount_tag                  = local.awsaccount_tag
  appid_tag                       = local.appid_tag
  security_groups                 = module.tst-security-group-alb.id
  env_tag                         = local.env_tag
  health_check                    = var.health_check
}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error like below:

```
Error: Argument or block definition required

  on main.tf line 52, in variable "listener":
  52: [

An argument or block definition is required here.
```

I am going to create a separate variable file later. At the moment I want to get basic skeleton working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `variable listener` must be `variable "listener"`. You are missing double quotes
2. a map should look like the below

```
variable "amis" {
 type = "map"
 default = {
   "us-east-1" = "ami-b374d5a5"
   "us-west-2" = "ami-4b32be2b"
 }
}
```

3. Finally, the variable listener is missing its definition. You have an array of key value pairs, but you are not specifying what type or description of the variable.

Comment: ! It helped me. Thanks for your help :)